# Choosing a controller/drive for a bare-glass SLCD

Tags: arduino, lcd, led-driver

I'm interested in playing with bare-glass SLCDs for low-power applications, so I picked up a few of [these](http://www.mouser.com/search/ProductDetail.aspx?r=696%2DLCD%2DS401M16KR) recently. It's four digit, seven segment, 1/4 duty, 1/3 bias SLCD with 12 pins. I'm unsure what controller or driver to look for to help run this thing, because I really don't know what to even look for in the datasheet. Any help would be appreciated. Through-hole would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the PICs, you also have access to the very nice MSP430 family, as well. Here is a table taken from one of the TI docs (SLAA654A):

[image: TI SLAA654A]

These are 16-bit ALUs with a dozen free registers and some decent clocking and very decent low power modes. They can come back from a dead sleep to full start in much faster times than the PIC nanowatt devices can achieve.

However, that said, I much prefer Microchip as a company to deal with. They support their products and they support their chips well. For a small hobbyist or small company doing design work, other things equal, I'd use Microchip anytime over TI. But the MSP430 is very nice and it's easier to get top quality C/C++ and assembly coding tools for it, at no cost, than is the case for the PIC (where it's possible, but you work harder to get there -- except for the assembler/linker for the PIC which is fine and free.)

Answer (score 1):

There are some PICs with on-board LCD drivers that can handle those requirements. No doubt other micros, but the PICs are available in classic through-hole packages.

Eg. PIC16F1902, PIC16F1933

Though personally I would prefer the PIC24xx series which is not available in through hole + LCD from what I can see. There may be some other series (eg. PIC18 or even PIC32, just do a parametric search).

Of course using these requires programming a micro.